# How to scroll whole listview vertically and its item scroll horizontally after click on listview item

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

My listview show a list of task. Each task have its sub task just under the its parent task. And sub-task also have its sub-task under it.

For e.g. I have task 'A'. Its have sub-task called 'AA'. And sub-task 'AA' have also its sub task called 'AAA'.

I want after click on task, its sub-task should open by shift to right side(horizontally) without compressing the data.

See the below image.

Image 1: https://slack-files.com/T0B5N0VDW-FMJ6HB78S-535918a01f

Image 2: https://slack-files.com/T0B5N0VDW-FMV62111S-b9c19d13f3

Image 3: https://slack-files.com/T0B5N0VDW-FMVKXFDV3-e78853fe2b

My problem is sub-task data get compress to after open. I want all sub-task open by shifting to right with all data.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are asking something like this. 
[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiIo8.png)

> This class is a part of RecyclerView, it attaches itself to the list item and handle swipe actions

*see the example code snippet*

```
public class SwipeToDeleteCallback extends 
ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {
private MyAdapter mAdapter;
public SwipeToDeleteCallback(MyAdapter adapter) {
super(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT);
mAdapter = adapter;
}

@Override
public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int 
direction) {
int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
    mAdapter.deleteItem(position);
}
```

Change your list to recyclerview because:
1. It solves your problem
2. It is more progressive and handle list items effectively.

Comment: Plz see the above images. Every time when I click on listview item it open its sub-task which is right sifted and text view get compressed. I want text view( sub-task) show without compressed form. And list move both ways i.e. horizontally as well as vertically.

Comment: I have a list view with 20 rows and I want to setup a horizontal scrollview for every row item in list view, as each row contains more than one item.

Comment: make a separate adapter for each of those item in the list view with horizontal orientation.